# rxJava and app lifecycle error

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room, rx-kotlin

I use rxjava to read from the room database on the Schedulers.io thread. I've noticed that when my app is killed and reopened it always crashes with

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
>   lock the UI for a long period of time.

I use MVVM architecture with Dagger and instantiate view model with lazy

```
private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(StudentsListViewModel::class.java) }
```

All my requests to database look like this:

```
compositeDisposable.add(viewModel.students
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext {
                    <I do things here>
                }
                .doOnError { it.printStackTrace() }
                .subscribe()
        )
```

I kill disposable onDestroy with

```
compositeDisposable.apply {
            clear()
            dispose()
        }
```

So, why is it crushing on recreate and what is it trying to do on the main thread?

My ModelView class:

```
class StudentsListViewModel@Inject
constructor(private val studioRepository: StudioRepository): ViewModel() {

val students: Flowable<List<Student>> = studioRepository.students

fun getStudentById(studentId: Int): Maybe<Student> {
    return studioRepository.getStudentById(studentId)
}

fun insertStudent(student: Student): Unit = studioRepository.insertStudent(student)
fun insertStudentFlat(student: Student) = studioRepository.insertStudentFlat(student)

fun updateStudent(student: Student) {
    studioRepository.updateStudent(student)
}

fun deleteAllStudents() {
    studioRepository.deleteAllStudents()
}

fun getStudentsNames(): Flowable<List<String>> = studioRepository.studentNames

val studentsCount: Flowable<Int> = studioRepository.studentsCount

fun getTicketById(ticketId: Int): Maybe<Ticket> {
    return studioRepository.getTicketById(ticketId)
}

fun getTicketByIdFlat(ticketId: Int): Ticket {
    return studioRepository.getTicketByIdFlat(ticketId)
}

fun updateTicket(ticket: Ticket) = studioRepository.updateTicket(ticket)

val activeTicketsStudentIds: Flowable<List<Int>> = studioRepository.activeTicketsStudentIds

fun getClassesByIdFlat(values: List<Int>): List<YClass> = studioRepository.getYclassesByIdFlat(values)

private fun getStudent(studentId: Int): Maybe<Student> = studioRepository.getStudentById(studentId)

private fun getAllActiveTicketsForAStudent(studentId: Int): Maybe<List<Ticket>> = studioRepository.getAllActiveTicketsForAStudent(studentId)

fun archiveStudentByIdAndDeactivateHisTickets(id: Int) {
    getStudent(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSuccess {
                it.isArchived = true
                studioRepository.updateStudent(it)
                getAllActiveTicketsForAStudent(id)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .doOnSuccess { list ->
                            list.forEach {
                                it.actual = false
                                updateTicket(it)
                            }
                        }
                        ?.subscribe()
            }
            .doOnError {
                it.printStackTrace()
            }
            .subscribe()
}
```

}

```
08-03 22:17:45.601 7776-7776/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlogOpenClasses E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlogOpenClasses, PID: 7776
    java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to start activity** ComponentInfo{com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlogOpenClasses/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.factory.AppViewModelFactory.create(AppViewModelFactory.java:55)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(StudentsActivity.kt:83)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(StudentsActivity.kt:69)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity.observeStudents(StudentsActivity.kt:136)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsActivity.onCreate(StudentsActivity.kt:103)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:204)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:232)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.database.dao.StudentDAO_Impl.getStudents(StudentDAO_Impl.java:272)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.repository.StudioRepositoryImpl.<init>(StudioRepositoryImpl.kt:50)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.di.AppModule.provideStudioRepository(AppModule.kt:26)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.di.AppModule_ProvideStudioRepositoryFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideStudioRepositoryFactory.java:24)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.di.AppModule_ProvideStudioRepositoryFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideStudioRepositoryFactory.java:10)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsListViewModel_Factory.get(StudentsListViewModel_Factory.java:17)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.activity.students.StudentsListViewModel_Factory.get(StudentsListViewModel_Factory.java:8)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.factory.AppViewModelFactory.create(AppViewModelFactory.java:53)
```

Comment: Could you share your `StudentsListViewModel`class?

Comment: @Anatolii I've updated question with my viewModel class

Comment: After allowing main thread operations in database setup problem was solved. But this is obviously not the way I want tot solve it.

Comment: I guess you're doing some db operations in doOnNext

Comment: do you have this code somewhere on github so that to try t out?

Comment: @saiedmomen I only run into the problem if app is recreated after being killed by the system. And, no, there is no db operations in onNext

Comment: @Anatolii Unfortunately I don't

Comment: What happens if you remove `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`from `viewModel.students`?

Comment: I suspect it is this line `val students: Flowable<List<Student>> = studioRepository.students` - as per stacktrace you are getting the students and this is evaluated immediately on the calling thread that instantiates the class.

Comment: @MarkKeen I call val students: Flowable<List<Student>> = studioRepository.students with subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) from the View

Comment: Yes, but it is evaluated immediately .. it is not deffered until subscription. Try `val students: Flowable<List<Student>> = Flowable.defer { studioRepository.students }`